# ExtJs4 how to read cookie using the store proxy

Tags: json, extjs, cookies, proxy, store

I have a combobox to enter URLs which I save to cookie in this way:

```
    Ext.util.Cookies.set("recentImportURLs", Ext.JSON.encode({'url_0': 'sometext'}));
```

Then I want to load this saved data to combobox:

```
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('recentImportUrl'),
```

using the store proxy.

So, does anybody know how to configure it correctly and set a path to cookie file in order to get this 'sometext' in my combo?

Comment: What does Ext.util.Cookies.get("recentImportURLs") give you back? Also looks like you may need at extra forward slash on the first half of your url config, so `http://localhost/webapp/`

Comment: Ext.util.Cookies.get("recentImportURLs") returns just this "{'url_0': 'sometext'}"
I've also tried to write in this way   `http://localhost/webapp/index.htm`